# Reparametrisation of closed not closed

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I would like an example of a closed curve and a reparametrisation of the same curve that is not closed.

Closed in the sense that it is periodic. i.e there exists $r\in \mathbb{R}-0$ such that $\gamma$ is not constant and $\gamma (t+r)=\gamma (t)$ for all $t$ in the considered domain.

Comment: Please make your question more specific. Closed in what sense(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a circle.  You know the periodic parametrization with $sin$ and $cos$.  Now just make it so that the parametrization winds around the circle faster and faster, so that there can't be a period.

E.g. Take the parameterization: $t \mapsto (\sin(e^t), \cos(e^t))$.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping ${\Bbb{R}}\longrightarrow{\Bbb{R}}^2$ given by
$$t\longmapsto\left(\begin{array}{c}\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}\\\\\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\end{array}\right),$$
re-parameterize the circle of radius one centered at the origin minus the point $\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\-1\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: experiment with http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%28%282t%29%2F%281%2Bt%5E2%29%2C%281-t%5E2%29%2F%281%2Bt%5E2%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C-5%2C5%7D you will see that each bounded interval centered a the origin is mapped to an arc of the circle.

Comment: another sample http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%28%282t%29%2F%281%2Bt%5E2%29%2C%281-t%5E2%29%2F%281%2Bt%5E2%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C-8.6%2C8.6%7D